# Sharepoint search - word document page level

Tags: search

In sharepoint search, can we set the searching permission for MS office documents (docx, pptx) into page level. I mean if we have a word document with 10 pages. can we set the page number 5 only searchable for a specific group or not?

As I can see now, Searching in sharepoint is based on sharepoint permission levels. it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible.  You can change how much of a document gets indexed by amount of bytes you read in, but not specific pages.

You could add in an additional column to include keywords for the document or link it via smart part in work to contain the information.

I'm not sure it will work but you can look into IRM which will let you restrict document sections based on user groups. However I'm not sure how it will react with Search.  When you store an IRM document in SharePoint it actually disables IRM in its stored state.